# Extracting span text

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the price from a website but can't seem to parse it.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www2.hm.com/en_ca/productpage.0938696002.html' 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'user-agent'}

page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

item_name = soup.find('h1', class_='primary product-item-headline').get_text().strip()

print(item_name)
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="price parbase"><div class="primary-row product-item-price"><hm-product-price id="product-price"><div class="ProductPrice-module--productItemPrice__2i2Hc"><span>$39.99</span></div></hm-product-price></div>
    </div>
```

I have omitted the URL and User-Agent intentionally :)
Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

ps. I have tried doing this;

```
# prices = soup.find_all('span', id = 'product-price')
# for price in prices:
#   print(price.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website is dynamically loaded; so, I would recommend you to grab `json` rather than static elements. If you go to [page source](http://view-source:https://www2.hm.com/en_ca/productpage.0938696002.html) and search for product price (in your case 39.99), you will see `script` tag:

```
<script id="product-schema" type="application/ld+json">
{"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "Product",
"itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
"image": "//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F41%2F00%2F410022bd8b8ae24cdd172fde77449354c7a0d6bd.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/main]",
"name": "Cargo Joggers",
"color": "Black",
"description": "Joggers in slightly stretchy cotton twill. Covered elastic at waistband, attached grosgrain belt with plastic buckle, and a small metal D-ring at front. Side pockets with zipper, back pocket with zipper, and leg pockets with flap and concealed snap fasteners. Covered elastic at hems.",
"sku": "0938696002",
"brand": {"@type": "Brand","name": "H&amp;M"},
"category": {"@type": "Thing","name": "Cargo"},
"offers": [{"@type": "Offer","url": "https://www2.hm.com/en_ca/productpage.0938696002.html","priceCurrency": "CAD",
"price": "39.99",
"availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
"seller": {  "@type": "Organization", "name": "H&amp;M"}}]}
</script>
```

You can get inner json fairly easy using `bs4`. Just need to **scrape** that tag, convert it to **string** and **load** as json:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www2.hm.com/en_ca/productpage.0938696002.html' 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'user-agent'}

page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'}).string
json_data = json.loads(data)

item_price = json_data['offers'][0]['price']
# -> '39.99'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this works. I've gone ahead and changed how I extract the product name as well to stay consistent.

Comment: Cool, check this out to see what to do when your question is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This data seems to be dynamically loaded and requires headers. There's other posts on SO that go into that, but I couldn't find a way to make that work. Search selenium and bs4 together.

However, the data is there in a script tag and can pulled out using the following code.

```
url='https://www2.hm.com/en_ca/productpage.0938696002.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'user-agent'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', id='product-schema').string)
print(data)
print(data['offers'])
print(data['offers'][0]['price'])
```

The data['offers'] key looks to be a list which means there can be more than one price at times, but using [0] will pull the first element of the list. In this ase $39.99

Comment: I tried this and this is the error that I get:                                                              
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: It works given the example you provided. If you can provide url or other information, it's difficult to troubleshoot. updated my answer to show my full code.

Comment: Understood, I updated my post with the URL. Also, in the HTML code, <div class="ProductPrice-module--productItemPrice__2i2Hc"> == $0 (when I click on this line, the == $0 can't be seen otherwise. it also says "use $0 in the console to refer to this element if I hover over '== $0'). Maybe that's an adjustment that needs to be made?